# Error in Doctrine 2 sandbox

Tags: php, doctrine

i am trying to get started with Doctrine 2. and i am reading their [intro](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/introduction/en). i am stuck trying to run

```
D:\Projects\Websites\php\Doctrine\sandbox>doskey doctrine=php d:\resourcelibrary\frameworks\doctrine\bin\doctrine.php $*

D:\Projects\Websites\php\Doctrine\sandbox>doctrine --version
Doctrine Command Line Interface version 2.0-DEV

// from here u can see that doctrine works ... i used doskey to shorten typing

D:\Projects\Websites\php\Doctrine\sandbox>doctrine orm:schema-tool:create ./entities

  [RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments.

orm:schema-tool:create [--dump-sql] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|--verbose] [-V|--version] [-a|--ansi] [-n|--no-interact
ion] command

D:\Projects\Websites\php\Doctrine\sandbox>
```

i thought this is more or less the exact same code as the tutorial?

## UPDATE

i discovered that in the package download from http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/download the sand box dont even have the folders entities, yaml & xml folders! the one from SVN ... i think onlye had the DBAL package (i think, in Doctrine) and the rest in lib. the structure seems off ... thats really a unusable beta?

which beta download can i use to start learning Doctrine 2?

Comment: yes i also tried using the full command `php d:\full\path\to\doctrine\bin\doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create ./entities` exact same error ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a better idea to download it using git, because that will allow you to get your dependencies (dbal and common).

```
git clone git://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git doctrine2-orm
cd doctrine2-orm
git submodule update --init
```

But the actual problem you are having is that you're passing an argument to orm:schema-tool:create where it doesn't want one. It looks like this behaviour was changed resulting in out-of-date documentation.

The following works for me:

```
cd tools/sandbox
./doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Which outputs:

```
Creating database schema...
Database schema created successfully!
```

Comment: yay!!! finally! so its true its old docs!! erm so now, i can assume that doctrine will look for the `Entities` folder to create the database? what abt the `xml` & `yaml` folders?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it takes that information from cli-config.php now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the note on that tutorial page?

```
The sandbox is only available via SVN or soon as a separate download on the downloads page.
```

I checked it out from `http://svn.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git` and it had the complete Sandbox environment.

Comment: i tried that but does it work for u? sandbox is ok there but lib has `Doctrine\ORM` only and `lib\vendor\doctrine-common` is empty

Comment: i have put the Doctrine folder containing `Common` and `DBAL` folders into `lib\vendor\doctrine-common` & `\doctrine-dbal` but `orm:schema-tool:create ./entities` still fails with `[Runtime Exception] too many arguments`

Comment: i think i must download `dbal` and `common` separately... but i still have the same too many arguments error