# ORM Framework to learn in Preparation for Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine, orm

i am currently learning Zend Framework 1.10 and intend to use Doctrine 2. however i see to encounter many problems/errors when trying to use the doctrine 2 sandbox.

- [Runtime Exception: Too many
  arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270596/doctrine-2-ormschema-toolcreate-giving-runtime-exception-too-many-arguments)
- [Error in Doctrine 2
  Sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270212/error-in-doctrine-2-sandbox)

i am wondering if doctrine 2 is not ready, what shld i learn that will be beneficial in preparing me for using it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO Doctrine 2 unfortunately is a long way off from being ready for Production use, for a few reasons:
- Not any of my client's webserver hosts support PHP 5.3 yet.
- It does fix many problems (cleaner by far), however it does make a lot of things more difficult (no templates, the entity manager).
- It has not reached widespread support yet as Doctrine 1 has. Barely any complete tutorials exist for using Doctrine 2 with Zend Framework.

As much as I'm dying to start using Doctrine 2 with Zend Framework, the above reasons always cause me to fallback on version 1. Perhaps when Zend Framework has reached version 2, then it would make sense.

In the meantime, Doctrine 1 is still a fantastic choice for using with Zend Framework. There are plenty of tutorials, resources and examples. I have it setup with the CMS we deploy, and currently the only long standing issue we have is migrations - however upon investigation it seems to be with our configuration settings.

Unless of course you want to learn Ruby on Rails, Doctrine 1 is by far the best alternative to get you ready for Doctrine 2.

Comment: the reason why i want to learn doctrine 2 is becos i like to learn the latest and greatest, whether or not i can use them in real work. in real work many times, i need to cut corners.

Comment: Yeah sure! But is there a point learning something which can cause more pain than woohoos? Which in my opinion is where Doctrine 2 is still at. Doctrine 1 remains very valuable great to learn, as nearly all of what you'll learn exploring Doctrine 1 will be applicable - plus it's stable! Or if you feel like trying something completely new, tryout Ruby on Rails 3 (it's in beta) - again same/similar concepts but way "cooler". Personally I've never bothered to learn RoR properly (as I'm already a pro with PHP so it would be too sacrificial to learn for myself), but it's potential is massive!